# x=random.random(), TypeError:'module' object is not callable

Tags: python-2.x

I have tried to debug this program but I don't know what the error refers to. When I run my code I get this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVgRR.png)

here is my code that you can refer to:

```
    import urllib
    fh=urllib.urlopen("http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt")
    for line in fh:
        print line.strip()
```

any help will be apprriciated

Comment: Does it give you a line for where it's breaking? There is nothing wrong in the code you've provided.

Comment: it breaks in many lines it breaks in line 84,line 205, line 289, line 79, line 6, line 34 , line 3

Comment: it is breaking in the line 3 it says module object =random, random.random()

Comment: You say it's breaking in lines all the way up to line 205, yet you gave us 4 lines. How do you expect us to solve your problem?

Comment: see I am giving the output that my code produced

Comment: do we have to download the urllib seperately

Comment: now the code is working I removed a file named "random.py" then it worked                                                                                                         the code of random.py is :                                  ó
Ó9)Vc           @   s8   d  d l  Z  x  e d ƒ D] Z e  j  ƒ  Z q We GHd S(   iÿÿÿÿNi
   (   t   randomt   ranget   it   x(    (    (    s*   C:\Users\user\Desktop\nik_python\random.pyt   <module>   s

Answer (score 0):

the bug was that in my folder I had named a file "random.py" and used "import random " in this file. So I changed the name of the file and re-ran my code.It worked. It was a silly mistake on my part.